# Typo3 DCE Container loop

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I want to make this code more flexible.

As you maybe can see, it's a code for DCE.

So I want to make it possible to add Quotes with a loop or some kind similar.

https://gist.github.com/DarthKeks/f5b3c9c26f05f3a8dfbf127dee9f9b64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In DCE you can use a section that repeats itself. Say you create a section with the variable ***quote***

**Navigation**

- *Iterator* can be anything, this allows you to loop an do stuff like
  counting or numbering. We use the iterator to see if an item is the
  first item, and add an active class.

For example:

```
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <f:for each="{field.quote}" as="quote" iteration="iterator">
            <li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="{iterator.cycle}" {f:if(condition: '{iterator.isFirst} == 1', then: ' class="active"')}></li>
        </f:for>
    </ol>
```

**Caroussel**

Same principle applies here:

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

    <f:for each="{field.quote}" as="quote" iteration="iterator">            
        <div class="item{f:if(condition: '{iterator.isFirst} == 1', then: ' active')}">
            <blockquote>
                <f:format.html>{quote.expert}</f:format.html>
                <small>{quote.expertName}</small>
            </blockquote>
        </div>
    </f:for>

</div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks, solved it on my own, but thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use [dce-containers](https://forge.typo3.org/projects/extension-dce/wiki/DCE_Container) Where your qoutes are now just add a 
Marker/Field and load in your DCE fields into that Marker/Field. As long as the DCE item is the same type it will loop trough.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is it possible for you to show me for my code example how i must split it right that it work?